# How do I find a list of available timeslots given scheduled dates from list in Excel/VBA sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of scheduled appointments already and want to be able to show all possible timeslots available between 7:30 AM - 5:00 PM for a **2 hour appointment.**  I've tried a visual and been able to get it through a hack, but I need to get it to work just from reading the below table

**SCHEDULED APPOINTMENTS**

`|---------------------|-------------------|
|   Start Date/Time   |   End Date/Time   |
|  6/12/2019 7:30 AM  | 6/12/2019 8:30 AM |
|  6/12/2019 8:45 AM  | 6/12/2019 9:15 AM |
|  6/12/2019 3:00 PM  | 6/12/2019 3:30 PM |
|  6/12/2019 3:45 PM  | 6/12/2019 4:15 PM |
|  6/12/2019 4:15 PM  | 6/12/2019 5:00 PM |
|---------------------|-------------------|`

**EXPECTED OUTCOME:**

- 6/12/2019 9:15 AM
- 6/12/2019 9:30 AM
- 6/12/2019 9:45 AM
- 6/12/2019 10:00 AM
- 6/12/2019 10:15 AM
- 6/12/2019 10:30 AM
- 6/12/2019 10:45 AM
- 6/12/2019 11:00 AM
- 6/12/2019 11:15 AM
- 6/12/2019 11:30 AM
- 6/12/2019 11:45 AM
- 6/12/2019 12:00 PM
- 6/12/2019 12:15 PM
- 6/12/2019 12:30 PM
- 6/12/2019 12:45 PM
- 6/12/2019 1:00 PM

Comment: Sounds like homework to me

Answer (score 1):

To get just that list directly would require VBA, which is possible, but StackOverflow is not a write-your-code-for you service. We would help if you got stuck with your code, but you need to know how to code in the first place and have made a start.

That said, if you accept a slightly easier solution, then a single formula can give you your desired result:

1. Convert your appointments range to a data table with column headings "Start" and "End"
2. Set the table name to "Appointments"
3. Store your new appointment length (2) in a cell and give it the name "Length"
4. Create a list of every possible appointment start time, starting from A1
5. Enter this formula next to the first time in B1, and save it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

`=AND((ROUND(Appointments[Start],4)>=ROUND(A1+Length/24,4))+(ROUND(Appointments[End],4)<=ROUND(A1,4)),ROUND(A1-TRUNC(A1),4)<=ROUND((17-Length)/24,4))`

Then fill down that formula against every time slot and it will say TRUE for the available time slots.

For each possible time slot, the formula checks that all existing appointments finish on or before the time slot or start 2 or more hours after the time slot. It also checks that there are at least 2 hours left in the day before finishing at 5pm. The formula handles different lengths required for the new appointment by changing the value in the "length" cell.

The ROUND functions are added to eliminate issues with floating point precision on fractions/times not always correctly identifying when 2 times are the same.

[image]